# Is it possible to check by json-scheme that required fields exist only?

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm writing an api endpoint. The parameter is raw JSON. I'm trying to validate it by JSON-schema (`org.everit.json.schema`). I want to define structure strictly, only described fields allowed.
I've looked through [JSON Schema doc](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-core.html) and still in doubt that it is possible. Does someone have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found a solution.
`"additionalProperties": false,`
this makes schema not allow properties which was not described.